# What is relation between openfl, flambe and awe6

Tags: haxe, openfl, flambe

I do know that all three can be used to make mobile games. And can create fast games. But i only know of openfl which i learned is something called nme but improved.

So i would like to know couple of things...first simply describe them and their relations..then their disadvantages plus advantages..and your preference and why.

Secondly, verify my assumptions...

- you need to know haxe.
- you need to understand openfl on top of ex. awe6?

Laslty can you summarize the workflow of how you go from idea to making app with openfl or and flambe/awe6...etc.

http://getflambe.com/

https://code.google.com/p/awe6/wiki/ProjectObjectives

Answer (score 3):

[OpenFL](http://www.openfl.org/) is not a game engine. It is a cross-platform tool based on Haxe and open-source implementation of Flash API. It allows to write and deploy applications to many different platforms from one codebase. Also you can find more info on OpenFL on its [github page](https://github.com/openfl/openfl).

Unlike OpenFL, Flambe and AWE6 are game engines. They can be compared to HaxeFlixel, HaxePunk and other [game engines based on Haxe](http://haxe.org/doc/libraries#game-frameworks). The main defference between these two is that AWE6 is using OpenFL to target platforms such as iOS and Adnroid, while Flambe is focused more on HTML5 and Flash games. It can be also used to target mobile targets, but native Android and iOS apps are packaged using Adobe AIR.

> you need to know haxe.

Yes, but if you already have some experience with Flash API and you are using OpenFL, the learning should be very easy.

> you need to understand openfl on top of ex. awe6?

AWE6 is based on OpenFL, so yes, but as far as I know, only basics. The main workflow is wrapped by game framework.
And the answer is "no" for Flambe, because it is not based on OpenFL.